# How to make tabs/sub-fragments inside a tab/fragment in Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-actionbar

I have implemented an ActionBar with 3 tabs in an android app. I also used ViewPager to switch between different tabs. Every tab is defined in a fragment.

The last tab is called "Setting". I have two different settings. One is "Simple" setting, and the other one is "Advanced" setting. How can I implement these two different settings in the "Setting" tab. Should I make kind of sub-fragments or two new tabs inside the main tab which is "Setting" tab? Can I also for example create two buttons at the top, and switch between them? Or any better idea? Which solution is easier and more efficient. I'm a newbie in Android.

I want to make something like this:

[image: Setting Tab]

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help

1. Take **SettingFragment** as Host fragment
2. Place both buttons on top and [ViewPager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.html) below buttons
3. Take **SimpleFragment** and **AdvanceFragment** as items in ViewPager